# Understanding Flutter's ShaderMask

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to understand how `ShaderMask` works. If I follow the example on the `ShaderMask` docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html):

```dart
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
    return RadialGradient(
      center: Alignment.topLeft,
      radius: 1.0,
      colors: <Color>[Colors.yellow, Colors.deepOrange.shade900],
      tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
    ).createShader(bounds);
  },
  child: const Text('I’m burning the memories'),
)
```

I get this:

[image: ShaderMask example output]

(the double lines below `Text` are apparently an indication of a lack of a `Theme`)

Then If I surround this same `ShaderMask` in a `Scaffold` I get this:

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
            return RadialGradient(
              center: Alignment.topLeft,
              radius: 1.0,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.yellow, Colors.deepOrange.shade900],
              tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          child: const Text('I’m burning the memories'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: ShaderMask with Scaffold]

It's all gone! the `ShaderMask` appears to have been just ignored, and there's no mention on the docs about this behavior, **why does the `Scaffold` ""disables"" the `ShaderMask`**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing - `blendMode` property

More info on - [blendMode property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask/blendMode.html)

working code:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ShaderMask(
          blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,  // Add this
          shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
            return RadialGradient(
              center: Alignment.topLeft,
              radius: 1.0,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.yellow, Colors.deepOrange.shade900],
              tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          child: const Text('I’m burning the memories'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Seeing the sample and sample on video it seemed the `blendmode` is optional. Confusion wasted time. Resolved here.